# How to redirect everyone from my website apart from me?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Basically, all I want to know is what is in the title of this question:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^11.11.11.111
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/www.mywebsite.site10.net/Stuff/randomfile.html\.html$ 
RewriteRule .* http://www.google.com [R=302,L]
```

11.11.11.111 being my IP address

Comment: does the redirection page have to be a html? or can i redirect them to Google.com?

Comment: The system I have at the moment works, but the website is being used to host data that other people have uploaded. I want to allow only ME to view the data on the website but I want people to be able a program I made (keylogger etc) and upload information from their computer to my website, but only I can view it. How could I edit it to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule \.html$ /anotherPage.html [R=302,L]
```

where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is your ip and anotherPage.html is the redirection page.

This is a 302 moved temporarily redirection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302